# How to crosscheck two tables and insert relevant data into a new table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to cross-check a row that exists in two tables using a MySQL query in phpmyadmin and then, if a `userID` is found in both tables, insert their `userID` and user name into another table. Here's my code:

```
INSERT INTO userswithoutmeetings
SELECT user.userID
IF('user.userID'='meeting.userID');
```

I keep getting plagued by this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near    
'IF('user.userID'='meeting.userID')' at line 3
```

Other statements I've tried have worked but not deposited the values in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
INSERT INTO userswithoutmeetings(userId,userName)
SELECT DISTINCT a.userId, a.userName
FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b ON (a.userId = b.userId)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat! Now I need to send the opposite data to another table. :/

Comment: INSERT INTO userswithoutmeetings(userId, contactName)
SELECT DISTINCT a.userId, a.contactName
FROM user b 
INNER JOIN user a ON (a.userId != b.userId);

I tried this but it adds the same data.